# From where does an electron gets its energy?

Tags: electrons, energy-conservation

From where does an electron get its energy to revolve around the nucleus?

If it continues its movement, then from where does it get the energy?

Comment: You could also ask this about the Earth and Sun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From where does electron gets energy to revolve around nucleus?

Both in classical mechanics, planetary systems, and quantum mechanics, atoms electrons molecules, bound states do not need energy to stay bound forever. This is axiomatic in the theories that describe the behavior of bound systems, as energy  momentum and angular momentum conservation.

In particular for the [atomic models](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/hydcn.html) there are no orbits, just [orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) where the electron can be stable in a quantized energy level forever, unless the atom  interacts with an external particle.

Reminder: in a planetary atom model there are no stable orbits because the electron would classically radiate away and fall on the positive nucleus. It is one of the reasons quantum mechanics was invoked, to explain the [spectra of atoms](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/spectra.html) . Bohr postulated axiomatically the quantization of angular momentum in order to fit  the spectra and have a working model of the hydrogen atom.